# How to remove mold/algae from the stones in a fish tank?

Tags: aquarium

I've noticed recently that the white stones in my fish tank
are starting to have something brown growing on them,
which I suspect to be mold/algae.
The mold/algae also seems to be slowly increasing over time.

1. How do I remove the mold/algae?
2. And how do I prevent the mold/algae from returning?

#### Edit

Here is a picture of my fish tank.
We have a filter which you can partially see at the back.
You can see that the white stones have some brown things on them,
but interestingly it only happens on some of the stones.
The fish tank also has several brown spots.

[image]

Comment: also what kind of rocks are they?

Comment: Can you please give some more information about your tank: How big is it, what fish are there, do you have heather and filter, how long is the tank already running, what maintence do you do, do you have real plants in it,... ? Answer to these questions will help in providing a better and more accureate answer.

Comment: @RebeccaRVT Added a picture. Not sure what rocks they are as my mother bought them.

Comment: @Diether No real plants, though we do have a filter.

Answer (score 2):

That could be [brown algae](https://www.thespruce.com/brown-aquarium-algae-1378629). 
It often occurs with new tanks, and should disappear after a while. 
Make sure you keep doing the regular maintenance. 
You can try to scrub it of with your fingers, and then siphon it up while you do your maintenance. Or, if it's harder to remove take the stones out and scrub them with a brush (I've get a toothbrush I only use for my tank). But don't use any chemicals. 
Preventing all algae is nearly impossible, but once you have a stable aquarium and regurarly maintain it, you should have less and you should be able to keep it under control.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why my previous answer about having couple of Bristlenose pleco in the tank was deleted. The point I was trying to make, They clean tank out in no time and keep it clean as long as they are in tank.